# What are the procedures for flight checking a glideslope and localizer?

Tags: faa-regulations, ils, icao-sarps, localizer, glideslope

What are the FAA and ICAO requirements and procedures for flight checks and calibration of glideslope and localizer transmitters? I'm interested in both the engineering and piloting aspects.

Answer (score 3):

It's all laid out in [Order 8200.1D](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/8200_1D_USSFIM_(04_15_15).pdf) United States Standard Flight Inspection Manual.

That and other documentation, including the inspection reports can be found from the FAA website under [Flight Inspection Information](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/avn/flightinspection/onlineinformation/).

Comment: Gerry what about ICAO ? And just to be clear i am more interested in knowing how to perform flight check not in reading the procedures only :)

Comment: The goal of flight check is to verify the "0 ddm" center of the LOC and G/S signals are propagating in the correct, straight (withing tolerance for bends and noise) path. The flight check a/c flies the approaches using a highly calibrated receiver that logs the data. At the same time a tracking system logs the actual location of the a/c. Older systems used a ground based laser tracker. Newer systems use a precision differential GPS system with a local reference ground station. The data  is the post processed to determine the actual path of the signal in space.

Comment: Can you summarize the main points of the doc in your answer? Link-only answers are generally not preferred here because pages move, documents are updated etc.